# iMacros - FILEDELETE

Tags: csv, imacros

I want to delete a file using iMacros. I read about "FILEDELETE" but I think I'm not using it correctly. Here is the code I am using:

```
FILEDELETE NAME=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\file1.csv
FILEDELETE NAME=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\file2.csv
FILEDELETE NAME=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\file3.csv
```

And this is the error I get from Imacros:

> expected absolute paths are prohibited for security reason as parameter 1, line: 4 (Error code: -911)

---

iMacros - Firefox (9.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox 55 or earlier and iMacros 8.9.7 to use file-commands with local file.